# what really controls the permissions: UID or eUID?

Tags: linux, credentials

Man page and many other sources clearly say:

```
       •  Real  user  ID  and real group ID.  These IDs determine who owns the
          process.  A process can obtain its real user (group)  ID  using  ge‐
          tuid(2) (getgid(2)).

       •  Effective user ID and effective group ID.  These IDs are used by the
          kernel  to determine the permissions that the process will have when
          accessing shared resources
```

So it should be quite clear that
eUID controls the actual permissions.
But the following test says otherwise:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    uid_t uid;
    uid_t euid;

    uid = getuid();
    euid = geteuid();
    printf("uid1=%i euid1=%i\n", uid, euid);
    system("ls /root");
    setreuid(euid, uid);
    uid = getuid();
    euid = geteuid();
    printf("uid2=%i euid2=%i\n", uid, euid);
    system("ls /root");
    return 0;
}
```

Building and running the test:

```
cc -Wall tst.c
sudo chown root:root a.out
sudo chmod u+s a.out
./a.out
uid1=500 euid1=0
ls: cannot open directory '/root': Permission denied
uid2=0 euid2=500
Desktop    Templates
```

So we see that with eUID=0 the listing
failed, but succeeded when UID became 0
(and eUID was intentionally changed to 500).

So from this test its quite clear that
UID does the actual checking.
Can someone please make the sense out of that?

Comment: The process executed by `system` does not inherit parent's euid. Never use `system`.